# How to prove that this sequence of functions is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of Lipschitzian functions (with same Lipschitz constant) over $(0, T)$ for which the inequality
$$ \left|\int_0^T x_n(t)^2 dt\right|\le \epsilon_n \|x_n\|_{\infty} +\int_0^T |x_n(t)| dt, dt $$
with $\varepsilon_n\to 0$.
It is possible to prove formally from the above inequality that $(x_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence? If it is true, how to do that?

About me it should be true since the LHS term has a quadratic growth and the RHS term has a linear growth, but it is just a naive idea.

Could someone please help with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $\varepsilon_n$ a specific sequence going to zero or any sequence going to zero?

Comment: @QC_QAOA not a specific one.

Comment: I assume the Lipschitz constant is the same for all functions? Otherwise, it is not true.

Comment: @Salcio so it is. I edit the question.

Comment: Bounded under which norm? $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ or $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: @FShrike bounded in $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea about quadratic growth is right if used in conjunction with the assumption that that the same Lipschitz contstant can be used for all $x_n$. Given that $x_n(t)$ all have the same Lipschitz constant $K$, we know that
$$  | x_n(t) - x_n(s)| < K|t-s| $$
for $s,t \in [0;T]$.  Since Lipschitz funtions are clearly continous we see that if $x_n(t_{n,\max})=|x_{\infty}|$ then for any $s \in [t_{n, \max}-1/K;t_{n,\max}+1/K]$ we have
$$   |x_n(t_{n,\max}) - x_n(s)| < 1$$
i.e.
$$ x_n(s) > ||x_n||_{\infty}-1.$$
But this obviously gives us that
$$   1_{[t_{n,\max}-1/K;t_{n,\max}+1/K]}(||x_n||_{\infty}-1)  < |x_n(t)| < 1_{[0;T]}||x_n||_{\infty},$$
hence we find
$$ 2/K (||x_n||_{\infty}-1)^2 <  \int_0^Tx_n(t)^2dt    $$
and
$$ \epsilon_n||x_n||_{\infty} + \int_0^T||x_n(t)||dt < (\epsilon_n + T)||x_n||_{\infty}$$
But if
$$2/K (||x_n||_{\infty}-1)^2 <  (\epsilon_n + T)||x_n||_{\infty}$$
we easily derive an upper bound for $||x_n||_{\infty}$, hence it cannot be unbounded.